# How to fill just string as long as column width and cut rest of string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have table in which i have one column which has string - with many letters, but I want just to fill one line column and if string is longer then I want to cut string for example:
"Lorem ipsum dori"
to:
"Lorem ips..."

But column in many computers have another resolution so i have to know how big column is or something like this.

How can I do this in AngularJS/JavaScript? There is any filter or something like this?
Because limitTo with static length is not solution.

Please help :)

Greetings,

rizon

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is setting a width on the column and using the CSS3 text-overflow [CSS Text-Overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)

```
.truncate {
    width: 250px; //modify this to your needs
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no cheap solution with JavaScript and AngularJS.

If it's sufficient to show only one line (not multi-lined), then use CSS:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS property,

```
{
  overflow : hidden;
  text-overflow : ellipsis;
}
```